# Flex deduction in paycheck 2015

Tags: fsa

My last day of work is 7/21/15, and the pay period ends on 7/26/2015. now

Would the checks received after 7/21/2015 have money deducted for HSA since I can not submit any expenses incurred after 7/21/2015 for Flex reimbursement?

The first deduction of 2015 Flex account had started in my first paycheck on 1/2/2015 and coverage is thru 7/21/2015 then why should the money be deducted from any check that comes out after 7/21/2015?

Comment: Do you mean FSA? I don't think you can have both an HSA and an FSA.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line up front:
First of all talk to HR. In all likelihood the last deduction from your paycheck will be the one that covers your last day of work.

A Health Savings Account (HSA) is not the same as a Medical Flexible Spending Account.

Assume for this answer that the last check on 30 July 2015 will pay you for all the hours worked, and that there are no other paychecks for vacation owed.

The check that you receive, whether it represents a full pay period or a partial pay period, will include all your deductions. HR will be able to tell you which ones will be full and which ones will be partial. It will depend on how the deductions and benefits are accounted for.

In general your health insurance coverage could end on either July 21st (last day of work),July 26th (last day of the pay period) or 31 July (end of the month). If you are being laid off it could even extend longer depending on the agreement.

A medical Flex spending account would be cutoff on either the last day of work or when the medical insurance ends. Any expenses incurred after that date would not be reimbursed. After the end of the plan year, or at the end of the extended plan year, all monies left in the account would be forfeited. You still can submit for reimbursement for those expenses from earlier this year that you have not yet submitted.

The good news about the medical Flex account is that if you spent more than you had deducted, you are in good shape they won't be asking for that money back.

This hard cutoff of access to the funds cause many people to try and spend at least to the amount that was deducted before the last day of coverage.

If this is a dependent card Flex spending account the rules about spending more than you have had deducted are completely different.

If you have a HSA because you have a High Deductible plan then your last check is the last time there will be a contribution from your check or from your employer. The good news is that you can either spend that money on medical expenses even after your last day of work, or you can save it; or you can cash it out. Cashing it out involves tax issues.

Comment: it is a Flex account. My health coverage ends on Aug 31st, I am told Flex reimbursement would be up to expenses incurred till 7/21/15 only.My question is, Would they be deducting Flex money from my paycheck after 7/21/15 paychecks?